# How to forward 80 port to 2 server based on donain

Tags: apache, multiple-domains

I have 2 apache server connected to a router. From the router settings, I can forward 80 and 443 port to a single machine/internal IP. Then I can access to it from my external IP address. My domain has A record pointed to that IP address. So, I am able to access to that machine using my domain.

But I want to use my both apache server for two different domain. Suppose, domain1.com will be connected to server1 and domain2.com will be connected to server2.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you got a single server with two websites and two domains you can simply create two VirtualHost blocks in your vhost config file. Both might look similar to each other but you have to change the `DocumentRoot` and the `ServerName` entry.

The file will look similar to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/Website1"
    ServerName Website1.com

    <Directory "/var/www/Website1/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/Website2"
    ServerName Website2.com

    <Directory "/var/www/Website2/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For sure you can also handle an https connection within this file.

Additionaly there are good ways of handlign the connection redirects with an `.htaccess` file in the desired root folder.